# Development and access the production host on same computer

Tags: php, apache

Problem is that the development is running same domain like example.com as the production server due to the facebook auth usage.

I can not set the development to different port as the facebook redirects to wrong url.

I am using LAMP stack and the development version domain url is set in /etc/hosts

Comment: You could set up a proxy server to route traffic from `http://development.example.com -> http://example.com:3000` or so.  Should work for facebook as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up `virtualhosts` and using the `hosts` file to override the DNS so that those domains point to `127.0.0.1`